# Unificationengine giving error when I am sharing message on intagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, unification, unificationengine

When I am sending posting a message by unificationegine then I am getting this error.But my password is correct

Exception in UEUser.php line 74: The password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.

I am using whole API by this format

**Instagram username and password (username=LOGIN_USER_NAME and password=LOGIN_USER_PASSWORD)**

```
$con = $access_token ."@instagram.com/?username=rajneesh8368&password='testing1'";

        $connection = $user->add_connection("instagramBoard", "instagram", $con);
        $options = array(
            "receivers" => array(
                array(
                    "name"=> "Me"
                )
            ),
            "message"=>array(
                "subject"=>"Transparentcom testing fine",
                "body"=> "Testing",
                "image"=> 'http://politibits.blogs.tuscaloosanews.com/files/2010/07/sanford_big_dummy_navy_shirt.jpg',
                "link"=>array(
                    "uri"=> '',
                    "description"=> "",
                    "title"=>"Click here for view"
                )
            )
        );
        //Send the message and get their uris
        $uris = $connection->send_message($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the updated version of SDK (https://github.com/unifiedinbox/ue-php-sdk), we are able to post to instagram.

We could see that you can now specify optional paramters while you add a connection.

The optional params for each connections are specified in documentation under 'Add connection' section https://developer.unificationengine.com/
In case of intagram, the optional params are "username"  and "password".